# How to add a clipping mask on this text

Tags: vector

[image]

How to add a clipping mask on this text(it is expanded) ?

Comment: your text layer seems to locked. that seems to be issue. unlock layer and then clip :)

Comment: still doesn't work, text keeps being colored in black instead of these red lines

Comment: Mask art **above** art to be masked in stacking order. You have it *below*.

Answer (score 2):

The text needs to be above the object it is clipping.  Also, there is no need to have text and object on separate layers in Illustrator.  Illustrator is very different from Photoshop.  Also you don't need to expand the text to outlines. It will work with editable text, or outlines, whichever you want.

Anyway, here's how to fix it. Ensure the text is placed on top of the object, select both, then do *Object > Clipping Mask > Make* or alternatively use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>.

This will create a clip group with the text and object being clipped.

Example:

[image]